# Generic base class to define custom data

Tags: c#, generics, base-class

I would like to add a ***Data*** object in some of my MonoBehaviour class.

So, I have created an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class DataMonoBehaviour<T> : MonoBehaviour 
    where T : BaseData, new()
{
    protected T Data;

    protected DataMonoBehaviour() 
    {
        Data = new T();
    }

    protected virtual T GetData()
    {
        if (Data == null)
            return default(T);

        return Data;
    }
}
```

I have also a class for my ***Data*** objects (it could be an interface):

```
public class BaseData { }
```

And some derived ***Data*** classes with properties on it:

```
public class DataA : BaseData { Property1, Property2 }
public class DataB : BaseData { Property1 }
```

So now I can create Monobehaviours associated with a ***Data*** object:

```
public class MonobehaviourA : DataMonoBehaviour<DataA> { }
public class MonobehaviourB : DataMonoBehaviour<DataB> { }
```

Is it good practice to do so?

If I want to get all my MonoBehaviour that inherites from DataMonoBehaviour (no matter the type of T) from a list. Should I have to create a base class to DataMonoBehaviour?

Then how can I convert the return items back to `DataMonoBehaviour` so I can do this:

```
((Cast to DataMonoBehaviour<T>)item).GetData();
```

to return my ***Data*** object associated with the DataMonoBehaviour

I don't know if it's possible to do so. If not, what are some possible solutions?

Comment: I have some remarks for you. In my point of view a BaseClass (like your BaseData) should always be abstract. Thats what I would expect. I also would not name an abstract class without abstract or base in name(like your DataMonoBehaviour) because its just confusing.

Comment: Could you tell us about the context you will be using this in? At the moment I don't see any use for this, you might as well just use T immediately, your DataMonoBehaviour has no purpose (that is, without seeing the rest of your code)

Comment: @Kenneth : It is for an Unity project http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity3D. In Unity, you can add scripts (a class that inherites from MonoBehaviour) to a GameObject. I would like to serialize the relevant data of my MonoBehaviour but MonoBehaviour can't implement ISerializable interface. That is why i want to add a custom data class to some of my MonoBehaviour. This data class will be serializable

Answer (score 0):

> **Is it a good practice to do so ?**

I think this is a possible way of solving the problem. I also would do it this way.

> **If a want to get all my MonoBehaviour that inherites from DataMonoBehaviour (no matter the type of T) from a list. Should i have to create a base class to DataMonoBehaviour ?**

I personally would use an interfaces. Then you could do somethink like this ...

```
public interface IDataMonoBehaviour
{
    BaseData GetData();
}
```

and iterate through the list ...

```
foreach(var monoBehaviour in monoBehaviourList)
{
    var behaviour = myBehaviour as IDataMonoBehaviour;
    if (behaviour != null)
    {
       // inherites from IDataMonoBehaviour 
    }
}
```

> **Then how can i convert the return items back to DataMonoBehaviour so i can do this...**

what about the following?

```
((IDataMonoBehaviour)item).GetData();
```